# Electron HLS video streaming mkv file from URL

Tags: node.js, angular, ffmpeg, electron, video-streaming

I am developing an Electron application and I need to play mkv video files from a URL like `http://example.com/videos/test.mkv` in my Angular front-end; but the problem is that the native HTML  tag does not support mkv files.
I have tried integrating video.js, hls.js and wcjs-player but I couldn't make it work.

Since I'm developing using Electron, I tried converting mkv files to mp4 using ffmpeg on the fly, send it to the renderer ipc and recieve it in Angular, but I couldn't make that work either.

I'm lost and would appreciate any help.

tldr; I want to be able to stream mkv files from url using Electron and Angular.

Comment: "but the problem is that the native HTML tag does not support mkv files"  Sure it does.  Are you compiling Electron in any particular way?  What platforms are you using your application on?  What codecs are used inside of your MKV?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create an electron player that can play anything that ffmpeg understands. The trick is two  tags, converting chops of about 20 seconds each in the backend and then flip flop the two video tags.
Using 2 video tags allows you to preload the next segment and start it just a few ms earlier before the other is ended to ensure that there is no gap.
The final code is rather complex, so I cannot share a short snippet. But this idea might help you going.

I looked for options to extend the open source Chromium with more video support, but that was too complex for me.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I have thought of doing that, but I failed to load the mkv file from the URL using ffmpeg. The documentation and the installed package seem to be different although I've installed the latest version. Also, I have no idea how to chop the video into chunks, and then stream them to the renderer ipc and feed it to the video player!

Comment: You send the mkv filename to the electron backend. There you can call ffmpeg to convert at given start/end time. Then you send filename of converted segment back to UI that loads it into <video>. Using custom protocol so that the backand can map the filename to a local file path. And all that in some loop per segment.
It's quite a lot development.